# How to prevent reload activity in android

Tags: android

Have Activity A ,here am retrieving data from server .On click of button am finishing current activity and start B activity ,on click of button again i want to go A activity by finishing B activity  but i dont want to reload A activity

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the lifecyle of an activity and the activity stack. developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. To know more about the  this developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. Go through the links and you should able to solve your problem.